# Ruby First Business Day of next month

Tags: ruby, date, time

I am trying to access the first BUSINESS day of next month. For example, if the end of the month is on a Saturday or a Sunday, I would like to spit out the following Monday's date, otherwise, I would like it to just return the first day of the month. So far, I have no problem accessing the first day of next month with

`Time.now.end_of_month + 6.hours`.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is Jan 1 a business day if it falls on a Monday?

Comment: Do you mean "business day", in which case you must account for holidays (including [these](http://list25.com/25-strangest-holidays-that-people-actually-celebrate/), for example), or "weekday"?

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

def next_month_1st_bday
  t = Date.today
  d = Date.new(t.year, t.month, -1)  # last day of current month
  d += 1 until d.wday.between?(1, 5) # no 0 (sunday) or 6 (saturday)
  d
end

p next_month_1st_bday # => #<Date: 2015-11-02 ((2457329j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm! **fist bump**

Answer (score 1):

The `business_time` gem is perfect for this.

https://github.com/bokmann/business_time

First install the required gems

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'business_time'
```

Now we can get the end of the current month

```
month_end = Date.today.end_of_month
```

Now, to get the first business day of the next month, simply do this

```
1.business_days.after(month_end)
```